# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCLWEBUT0001: Session is invalid

Tags: session, wildfly, infinispan

I'm encountering the following error message in my Java application running on WildFly20.

2024-02-06T17:34:31.231449538Z stdout F     at org.apache.velocity.tools.struts.StrutsUtils.getLocale(StrutsUtils.java:158)
2024-02-06T17:34:31.231446818Z stdout F     at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.getAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
2024-02-06T17:34:31.231444118Z stdout F     at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.getAttribute(DistributableSession.java:160)
2024-02-06T17:34:31.231441408Z stdout F     at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.validate(DistributableSession.java:278)
2024-02-06T17:34:31.231438598Z stdout F     at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.validate(DistributableSession.java:286)
2024-02-06T17:34:31.231435878Z stdout F Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCLWEBUT0001: Session QqiPQCoZqH2EVa_pTTimFUA0iAMdF-yzZHnhE57f is invalid

This seems to relate to session management, but I'm unsure about its cause. I've checked the application code and can't find any explicit session invalidation calls.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.